# Bitbucket Permissions - Avoid direct push to specific branch

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I want to disable write access or any direct commit on `release/*` and `main/master`, the only way for these branches to get update is via merge/pull request coming from **feature, hotfix, bugfix, or develop** branches to avoid trouble. How can I enforce such rule? Currently exploring **Branch permission**.

[image]

[image]

While allowing everyone that has access to the repository a pull from **release** and **main/master** and direct commit only on **feature, hotfix, bugfix, or develop** branches

[image]

[image]

Not sure if my understanding and what I am doing is correct as other user aside from Bitwise can still direct push to master branch.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't allow delete access either. Consider removing write access too?

Comment: @evolutionxbox isn't already included in a write access? I want a single person that acts like an admin to have the only write access or can direct commit to these branches.

Comment: But at the moment, all bitwise devs have permission to commit directly to those branches. That seems to conflict with the first desire in the question?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I updated the question, can you look at it again? Probably my understanding is not correct. Thank you

Comment: @evolutionxbox you have a point, maybe not a single person should have direct commit to `main/master` and `release`?

Comment: I would think no-one would be allowed write access except the person who is admin?

Comment: @evolutionxbox For `main/master` and `release` branch I want only the admin to have a direct push permission.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that direct push is write access